# Intersymbol interference on PAM Trasmitter

Tags: digital-communications, interference, telecommunications

I would like to simulate on Matlab a PAM signal which, travelling on a time-dispersive communication channel, contains intersymbol interference (ISI).

I have 'built' the transmitter by generating:

- 8-PSK signal
- designing the impulse response p(t) of a root of raised cosine
- upsampling
- filtering

So I have the signal ready to transmit ... but without ISI.

**In which of these steps should I add the ISI? And how do I do that?**

In my opinion, since I have to simulate 'L' echoes of a time-dispersive channel, in transmission I don't have p(t) but a delayed version of it .. so the impulse is already born with echoes .. for example like this: p(t)+a1*p(t-Ts) with Ts=symbol interval.

Is this correct?

If yes, then I should modify this step:
[image]

---

**EDIT**:
As I said, I would like to simulate on Matlab a PAM transmitter signal which, travelling on a time-dispersive communication channel, contains intersymbol interference (ISI).
How do I do it?
Delaying the raised root cosine filter pulses p(t) in the transmitter .. for example p(t)+a1*p(t-Ts) with Ts=symbol interval.

Correct?

So basically I have two filters:

- the first filter generates the coefficients (without delay) of RRC impulse given by coeff=rcosdesign(...)
- the second filter adds the delay/ISI to the coefficients generated by the first. So the output of the first filter is the input of the second one

Here is the Matlab code:

```
coeff = rcosdesign(alpha=0.35, L=30, Ns=10, 'sqrt') % Ideal! Without delay
% now I delay the the coeff by 3 samples:
z = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]; % 0 + 0*z^-1 + 0*z^-2 + 0*z^-3 ... 1*z^-8;
coeff_delay = filter(z3,1,coeff);
subplot(2,1,1);
stem((-L/2:1/Nc:L/2),coeff)
title('RCC Impulse response :)');
subplot(2,1,2);
stem((-L/2:1/Nc:L/2),coeff_delay);
title('RCC Impulse response + delay :(');
```

[image]

Comment: It's generally more useful to have separate models for the signal and the channel, rather than trying to combine everything into one stage. Since you have your signal model, just create a channel model using, for example, an FIR filter to generate your echoes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
In the FIR filter formula y[n]=b0x[0]+b1x[n-1]+....+bnx[n-(N-1)] .. N is the number of echoes, y[n] is the signal with the echoes and x[n] would be the impulse response of the raised cosine? Or is it the signal (without ISI and echo) that I produced after all the steps listed in my question?

Comment: x[n] is the signal from your signal model. Each nonzero b[n] in the FIR filter represents a discrete echo.

Comment: @DaveTweed In the final stage of my transmitter I filtered my signal with the Matlab function **filter(coeff, 1, seq_upsample)** which, precisely, filters the input using a rational transfer function. In the function just mentioned, 
coeff=filter numerator (coefficients of raised cosine pulse), 1=denominator and seq_up=input data that is to be filtered, i.e. the upsample sequence of Nc samples per symbol.

I do not understand if these steps just listed add ISI or if I have to filter further with an additional step.

Comment: @DaveTweed Perhaps to add ISI (from what I understand) I should change or modify this 'filter' function to that of a FIR filter ... am I wrong?

Comment: It's up to you. The raised-cosine filter is part of your signal model. I still recommend leaving that as it is, and feeding its output to a second filter that represents your channel model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141737/discussion-between-kalem-and-dave-tweed).